# Why the password is not hashed?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, password-hash, argon

I'm using Argon2 to hash my password, this is my code:

```
import { ForbiddenException, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaService } from 'src/prisma/prisma.service';
import { AuthDto } from './dto';
import * as argon from 'argon2';

  async signup(authDto: AuthDto) {
    // generate the password
    const hash = await argon.hash(authDto.password);
    console.log(`The hashed password is ${authDto.password}`);

    // save the new user in the db
    try {
      const user = await this.prisma.user.create({
        data: {
          email: authDto.email,
          hash: authDto.password,
          firstname: '',
          lastname: '',
        },
      });
      //delete user.hash;
      // return the saved user
      return user;
    } catch (error) {
      // test if the error is commimg from prisma
      if (error instanceof PrismaClientKnownRequestError) {
        // test if the field is duplicated
        if (error.code === 'P2002') {
          throw new ForbiddenException('Credentials taken'); //NestJS exception
        }
      }
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

When I print my hashed password, I find it not hashed.

PS : I'm using NestJS as nodeJS backend framework, and Manjaro Linux as OS, Argon2 as hash library.

Comment: The hash is in `hash` and not `authDto.password`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hashing the password you are still using the plaintext password for logging and storing it into the prisma db.
The variable `hash` contains the hashed password.

Change the code to use the `hash` instead of `authDto.password`.

```js
const hash = await argon.hash(authDto.password);
console.log(`The hashed password is ${hash}`);
```